# C# making own button and passing argument

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

We use C# form applications as HMI for our Automation projects. 
While doing this we generally use button click events. These events are changed boolean values from false to true. My problem starts here.
There are lots of boolean and if I add button events one by one, I will spend many many times. So I want to do my own button component and. I will drag and drop my button from toolbox and relate it with a boolean using properties window. After doing this, It will do everything automaticly instead of me. Button design is not important for me.

Example:

```
//Define Variables
public class PLCVars
{
    public bool PLCVar1;
    public bool PLCVar2;
    public bool PLCVar3;
    public bool PLCVar4;
    public bool PLCVar5;
    public bool PLCVar6;
    public bool PLCVar7;
    public bool PLCVar8;
}

//(!)I have a PLCVars object defined as PLCVariables
//Button Events 
private void button_JogPLCVar1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    PLCVariables.PLCVar1 = true;
}

private void button_JogPLCVar1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e
{
    PLCVariables.PLCVar1 = false;
}
```

As shown above example, I want to relate my button component with a plc variable. It will make all mouseup and mousedown events automaticly and change the value of plc variables.

As I searched, I should use Custom Control. But I don't know relating form variables with Custom Control components is posibble. If it is possible how?

Comment: Can you please clarify some parts of your question. **There are lots of boolean  and if I add button events one by one** - What boolean? Is it like `bool x = false;`? How you add events to boolean? Show us this code. **relate it with a boolean using properties window** - what does it mean? How you relate button with boolean?

Comment: I edited my question with adding code parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for custom control. Subscribe all buttons to these two event handlers. All you need to do is get `PLCVar#` field name. And you can use button's `Tag` property for that. Assign field name to tags `PLCVar1`, `PLCVar2` etc. Then get field name in event handler and assign value via reflection:

```
private void button_JogPLCVar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    SetPLCVariable((string)button.Tag, true);
}

private void button_JogPLCVar_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    SetPLCVariable((string)button.Tag, false);
}

private void SetPLCVariable(string fieldName, bool value)
{
    Type type = typeof(PLCVars);
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(fieldName);
    fieldInfo.SetValue(PLCVariables, true);
}
```

Creating and subscribing all buttons

```
 panel1.Controls.Clear();

 for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
 {
     Button button = new Button();
     button.Name = "Button" + i;
     button.Tag = "PLCVar" + i;
     button.MouseUp += button_JogPLCVar_MouseUp;
     button.MouseDown += button_JogPLCVar_MouseDown;
     panel1.Controls.Add(button);
 }
```

NOTE: It's better to use properties instead of public fields. For properties you will need to use `type.GetProperty` method. Also it's better to use `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Should I create mouseup and down events for all buttons? How will I relate buttons and these two events?

Comment: Okay I will subscribe buttons to these two functions. I will try. But especialy I want to create my own Autimation library on C#. I will use lots of things like textbox, picturebox, radiobutton etc. Should I use this method everytime or create my own dll as I ask on my question? Which one is better?

Comment: @tebdilikiyafet stackoverflow is not about writing dll guidelines. It's for solving particular problems with your code

Comment: @tebdilikiyafet I have much better solution for you. Hold on, I'll update answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by putting a Panel into the Form and create Button control's dynamically and also attach events to the created controls.

Here is a row example (you have to modify it)

```
public class PLCVars
{
    public bool PLCVar1;
    public bool PLCVar2;
    public bool PLCVar3;
    public bool PLCVar4;
    public bool PLCVar5;
    public bool PLCVar6;
    public bool PLCVar7;
    public bool PLCVar8;

    public bool[] BooleanVars()
    {
        return new bool[] { PLCVar1, PLCVar2, PLCVar3, PLCVar4, PLCVar5 };
    }
}

public void Method()
{
     PLCVars v = new PLCVars();

     panel1.Controls.Clear();

     for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
     {
         Button button = new Button();
         button.Name = "Button" + i;
         button.MouseUp += delegate 
         {
             v.BooleanVars()[i] = false;
         };
         button.MouseDown += delegate
         {
             v.BooleanVars()[i] = true;
         };

         panel1.Controls.Add(button);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Same logic with Sergey.

Comment: Yeap... saw that after he posted. But I have to ask... why you need to create a separate method and use reflection when you can just use delegates? It is faster and cleaner than that implementation.

Answer (score 1):

After your update I see that you want to create some buttons and manage properties of some object with these buttons. Here is much better solution.

First - you should use `FlowLayoutPanel` to host your buttons. Buttons will be located dynamically.

Second - you should not use buttons. Use `CheckBoxes` with button's appearance. Because you need to manage boolean properties.

Thirs - you should change `PLCVars` fields into properties. Because we are going to use data binding. And it doesn't work with fields:

```
public class PLCVars
{
    public bool PLCVar1 { get; set; }
    public bool PLCVar2 { get; set; }
    public bool PLCVar3 { get; set; }
    public bool PLCVar4 { get; set; }
    public bool PLCVar5 { get; set; }
    public bool PLCVar6 { get; set; }
    public bool PLCVar7 { get; set; }
    public bool PLCVar8 { get; set; }
}
```

Now you don't need any event handlers or custom buttons. If you want to create UI to control properties of `PLCVariables` object you just need to add checkboxes to panel and bind them to your object. Easy:

```
int numberOfVlcVariables = typeof(PLCVars).GetProperties()
      .Count(p => p.Name.StartsWith("PLCVar"));

for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfVlcVariables ; i++)
{
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
    cb.Text = "PLCVar" + i;
    cb.DataBindings.Add("Checked", PLCVariables, "PLCVar" + i);
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cb);
}
```

That creates and arranges toggle 'buttons'. And each button controls appropriate property of `PLCVariables` object. I.e. when button is pressed down, it means property set to `true`. If button is up, then property is equal to `false`.

[image]

And even more simple, but less cool option - you can simply add `PropertyGrid` control to your form and assign `PLCVariables` object to it:

```
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = PLCVariables;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your example is the best solution. I have forgotten about DataBinding. +1 from me

Comment: I don't want to add buttons dynamicly in a for loop. I will add button manually when I want. I will write its tag. Thats it. So I don't need FlowLayoutPanel I think. I only want to make simple my work.  I am very confused now. You can think like that I need only numeric textbox and I don't want to write the control functions for all textbox.